# how we can prevent user from navigating away using ui.router

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why i am unable to prevent user from navigating away from the current page in my angularJs1 application by using following code `event.preventDefault()`. Any Solution??

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function (event) {
    if (!confirm("Are you `enter code here`sure you want to go back??")) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try this example with a built-in service for confirmations: [Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/APz0s4uLD0vQ23IqIHMH/preview) (_try editing the text on Home page_). It uses `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', fn)` and cancels transition with `$q.reject();`

Comment: Do preventDefault on `$locationChangeStart` event. `$locationChangeSuccess` event is too late.

Answer (score 0):

$locationChangeSuccess indicates the successful change of the location
 , so the user is already redirected by this level..you should change that I think

Comment: how i can change it??Any solution??